# How do I extract sub string up to a specific word?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am given a list of locations:

```
location
Smith St
Smith Street 
10 Happy Lily Rd 
52 Happy Lily Road
Abraham St
```

The following is what I hope to achieve:

```
location
Smith Street
Happy Lily Road
Abraham Street
```

May I know how can I do that using regexp? Thank you!!

Comment: Can you please add a rule to judge which entry is ok and which one isn't? Would `Abraham St`be valid if there's no `Abraham Street`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for highlighting that. I've added that!

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough, and people prefer that you're showing what you have tried so far.

Comment: what if there's 'Road Lane 101'? is it still a valid road?

Comment: Hmm basically, I want to group all the same roads/streets together. However, due to the different spelling variations, I ended up having 'St' , 'Rd' etc in my list. I do not want the digits before the road names, so for '10 happy lily road' and '52 happy lily road', i want it to be just 'happy lily road' so that i can count the number of 'happy lily road' in total.  

Simply put, I want the street/road name without any numbers. And I do not want anything after the word 'st/street/rd/road' etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a special reqirement here to group strings with some ambigiousity (Rd & Road, St and Street, no numbers), you'll need to equal the strings first to be able to compare them. Afterwards, you can simply use a group by (or distinct) to eliminate doubles.

```
with testtab AS(
  select 'Smith St' as LOCATIONCOLUMN from dual 
  union all
  select 'Smith Street' from dual
  union all
  select '10 Happy Lily Rd ' from dual
  union all
  select '52 Happy Lily Road' from dual
  union all
  select '52 Happy Lily road' from dual
  union all
  select 'notstreetorRoad' from dual
  union all
  select 'notstreetorRd' from dual
  union all
  select 'good road' from dual
)
select formatedLoc
from (select trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(LOCATIONCOLUMN, 'St *$|Street *$', 'Street', 1, 0, 'Rd *$|Road *$', 'Road', 1, 0, 'i'), '\d', '')) as formatedLoc
       from testtab) formatedTab
group by formatedLoc;
```

yields

```
FORMATEDLOC                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-----------------
Happy Lily Road
notstreetorRoad
good road
Smith Street
```

It replaces St with Street, Rd with Road, removes all numbers and finally trims the result. Then you may easily eliminate doubles.

As this is very specific, you'll have to add other possible ambigious strings yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There was no proper structure or information to retrieve data from the table. Let me assume, you want to retrieve address with fill words.

```
SELECT location FROM TABLE1 WHERE location LIKE '%Street%' OR location LIKE '%road%'
```

Comment: Hi Vignesh Kumar A, yes, the location does not follow any proper structure as those are keyed in manually by the internal staff. I am supposed to find the top 10 accident prone areas hence I need to get the street/road names.

Comment: I'd recommend putting `location` either in `UPPER` or `LOWER` function to avoid not getting a result solely based on cap letters. For example, current query as you've written it wouldn't return `Happy Lily Road`

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query. I added `space` on the selection so `'notstreetorRoad'` will not be included

```
with cte(location) AS(
  select 'Smith St' from dual 
  union all
  select 'Smith Street' from dual
  union all
  select '10 Happy Lily Rd ' from dual
  union all
  select '52 Happy Lily Road' from dual
  union all
  select 'notstreetorRoad' from dual
  union all
  select 'good road' from dual
)
select * from cte where  REGEXP_LIKE(lower(location), ' road| street| st| rd')
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response :-) I have edited my qn and unfortunately this might not work now.